# VB.Net XML Parsing Issue

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, httpresponse

I am having some difficulty parsing some XML information in to a richtextbox. I am pulling an XML file from a stream and the data is coming through successfully but when I try to view the elements I think there is a problem.

Here is a snippet of the stream after it has been loaded(there are usually values next to each form name)

"< form name="SupportRepID">1234< /form>

< form name="SupportRepName">John Smith< /form>

< form name="SupportRepKey">XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX< /form>

< form name="DepartmentID">1< /form>

< form name="DepartmentName">General< /form>

< form name="DepartmentCurrency">$< /form>"

My end goal is to be able to grab the SupportRepKey and the SupportRepName.

the problem I think lies with each name under < details > not being classified as an Element. When I run the code like this to try and get the value for "SupportRepKey" the messagebox will show a null value(blank).

```
Dim reader As XDocument = XDocument.Load(dataStream)



    For Each detail As XElement In reader...<details>
        Dim APIKey As String = detail.Element("SupportRepKey")
        MessageBox.Show(APIKey) 'returns null value
    Next
```

If I run it with this(for troubleshooting to make sure the XML file is being pulled from the dataStream):

```
 Dim reader As XDocument = XDocument.Load(dataStream)

    For Each detail As XElement In reader...<details>
        MessageBox.Show(detail.Value) 'returns all values in one long string
    Next
```

It returns all the values next to each  < form name=""> in one long string: "1234JohnSmithXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX1General$"

I am using an API to interact with system where I work. The RepName and RepKey are generated anytime someone enters their log in information and every rep has a seperate key. I need to be able to grab just these two things and set them as variables or as text in a text field so I can further interact with API per user.

I think it has something to do with the objects under < details > being form name="" but I have looked everywhere for the past two days and come to no help. Maybe I'm not searching for the right terms, but I love this site. Everyone is always so helpful so I guess I'll try my luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Element** you want is "form" which has an **Attribute** "name" which has the value "SupportRepKey".

What you are doing is: Find the Element "SupportRepKey".

```
detail.Element("SupportRepKey")
```

But this does not exist, cause the Element name is "form". "SupportRepKey" is just the value of an attribute called "name".

How about using an XPath?

C#:

```
string repKey = reader.XPathSelectElement("//form[@name='SupportRepKey']").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks so much ec8or! This works perfectly, after some tweaking for vb but flawless non the less!

Answer (score 0):

Attributes is what your after, not fully sure what the change to your code would be but a change to looking at the attributes would allow you to pull out this data.

detail.Element("form").Attribute("name")

Comment: I tried tweaking the code for this method too but the answer from ec8or below was just what I needed. I have to call much more data in further areas of the API and with that I can get just what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good ! (Item worth noting is it can be beneficial to cache (in your case the form object) as using // can be quite slow as it searches the whole XML tree)